# Last 3 years from current date

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the last 3 years from current date in sql.

```
Select *
From table
Where year(column) >= year(current_date()) -3
```

I am only getting current year.. I need current year and last 3 years.

I tried:

```
Select *
From table
Where column > current_date() - interval 3 year
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Comment: No way this question is not a duplicate

Comment: Do you want *exactly* 3 years ago from now (ie same date in year), or do you want the *whole year* (ie from Jan 1) of the year 3 years back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Subtract exactly a year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247060/sql-subtract-exactly-a-year)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
From table 
where column = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 YEAR);
```

This will work on column with DATE type.

Comment: You don't know whether this will work because `DATE_ADD` and `NOW` are not available on all RDBMS. Better let the author of the question tag their RDBMS rather than guessing which one they use.